# Can I load a class from a specific class annotation value

Tags: annotations

I have classes with annotation like below. I know I can use reflections to get all classes with this type of annotation. But is there a way I can just load the class with the specific annotation name="demo1"?

```
@Demo(name="test_number")
public class Test1{
    ....
}
@Demo(name="test_string")
public class Test2{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the annotated classes, inspect annotation details, and filter classes with name ="demo1" only.

There is an API to read annotations details, read this article:

https://medium.com/@nadundesilva/reading-annotations-at-run-time-using-the-java-reflections-api-ce175ba43b2